# Extract a value from an Observable in RxJs

Tags: rxjs

I know I can subscribe to an object of type `Observable` if I need to extract a value from it, but what if I want to use operators from `RxJs` to reach the same goal. Please see the following code

```
this.placeService.getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId')).pipe(
        take(1), 
        tap(place => { console.log('Place: ' + place); this.place = place; }));
```

What is wrong? Why it does not work as expected (`this.place` is equal to `undefined`)?

Comment: You have to subscribe

Comment: `subscribe` IS "an operator from RxJs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to observable.

```
this.placeService.getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId'))
  .pipe(
    take(1), 
    tap(place => { console.log('Place: ' + place); this.place = place;}))
  .subscribe();
```

the same use without tap

```
this.placeService.getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId'))
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(place => { console.log('Place: ' + place); this.place = place;});
```

Comment: should I unsubscribe?

Comment: Take(1) takes only one value and do unsubscribe in backdrop

Comment: what about another case: `this.placeService.getPlace(paramMap.get('placeId')).subscribe(place => this.place = place);` Should I unsubscribe here?

Comment: If you have hot observable you have to remember about unsubscribe. The best way to unsubscribe from hot observables is using the takeUntil rxjs operator.

Comment: method getPlace() use httpClient inside? HttpClient methods return completed observables so you don't have to unsubscribe and take(1) is unnecessary too.

Comment: No, there's method `asObservable` called on `BehaviorSubject` object.

Comment: So it's hot observable.

Comment: You add in your component filed `private readonly destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject()` and implement ngOndestroy method, in this method: `this.destory$.next();this.destroy$.complete()` and in all hot observable add as last operator in pipe: `takeUntil(this.destroy$)`. It will unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

Comment: You can all so use the async pipe to handle the subscription and unsubscription.